# AFX_WM_ON_MOVE_TAB notification from CMFCTabCtrl

Tags: mfc-feature-pack

In my application I have 3 tabbed panes, I am tracking/capturing AFX_WM_ON_MOVE_TAB  in my mainframe class.

The tab control sends current and previous active tab . It doesn't send its window handle.

SendMessage(AFX_WM_ON_MOVE_TAB, m_iTabBeforeDrag, m_iActiveTab);

how will I know which tab control sends this message?

Answer (score 1):

Give each tab control a parent window that goes in between your mainframe and the tab. Then when the tab control sends its message to its parent, you know which tab control it came from.

Instead of:

```
 MainFrame
 |   |   |
TC1 TC2 TC3
```

Use:

```
 MainFrame
 |   |   |
 X1  X2  X3
 |   |   |
TC1 TC2 TC3
```